# For-loop error: list index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, list, class, for-loop

So I am rather new to programming and just recently started with Classes and we are supposed to make a phonebook that can be loaded in seperate text files.

I however keep running into the problem in this section that when I get into the for-loop. It hits a brick wall on

```
if storage[2] == permaStorage[i].number:
```

And tells me "IndexError: list index out of range". I am almost certain it is due to permaStorage starts out empty, but even when I attempt to fill it with temporary instances of Phonebook it tells me it out of range. The main reason it is there is to check if a phone number already exists within the permaStorage.

Anyone got a good tip on how to solve this or work around it?

(Sorry if the text is badly written. Just joined this site and not sure on the style)

```
class Phonebook():
  def __init__(self):
      self.name = ''
      self.number = ''

def Add(name1, number1):
  y = Phonebook()
  y.name = name1
  y.number = number1
  return y

def Main():
  permaStorage = []
  while True:
      print " add name number\n lookup name\n alias name newname\n change name number\n save filename\n load filename\n quit\n"
      choices = raw_input ("What would you like to do?: ")
      storage = choices.split(" ")
      if storage[0] == "add":
          for i in range(0, len(permaStorage)+1):
              if storage[2] == permaStorage[i].number:
                  print "This number already exists. No two people can have the same phonenumber!\n"
                  break
              if i == len(permaStorage):
                  print "hej"
                  try:
                      tempbox = Add(storage[1], storage[2])
                      permaStorage.append(tempbox)
                  except:
                      raw_input ("Remember to write name and phonenumber! Press any key to continue \n")
```

Comment: Why `len(permaStorage)+1` in `for i in range(0, len(permaStorage)+1):`?

Comment: I added it to have a defined range equal to the length of the permaStorage. The +1 was to get it to start in the first place, but most likely not necessary and will cause problems later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is that permaStorage is empty list and then u try to:

```
for i in range(0, len(permaStorage)+1):
          if storage[2] == permaStorage[i].number:
```

will cause an error because permaStorage has 0 items but u trying to get first (i=0, permaStorage[0]) item.

I think you should replace second if clause with first one:

```
for i in range(0, len(permaStorage)+1):    
    if i == len(permaStorage):
              print "hej"
              try:
                  tempbox = Add(storage[1], storage[2])
                  permaStorage.append(tempbox)
    if storage[2] == permaStorage[i].number:
              print "This number already exists. No two people can have the same phonenumber!\n"
              break
```

So in this case if perStorage is blank you will append some value and next if clause will be ok.

Comment: Thanks! It did work, it does however cause a small problem with that in the second part it prints out the "his number already exists. No two people can have the same phonenumber!\n" but that is a minor issue that is easily fixed.

Comment: Yeah, u can add an additional verification at the start of for-loop than "permaStorage" is empty, for example: if not permaStorage: tempbox = Add(storage[1], storage[2])
                  permaStorage.append(tempbox)

Answer (score 0):

Indexing starts at zero in python. Hence, a list of length 5 has the last element index as 4 starting from 0. Change range to `range(0, len(permastorage))`

Comment: Thanks! Sadly it does however not solve the issue, since the length of the permaStorage is starting empty. The error it runs into is when it attempts to check `if storage[2] == permaStorage[i].number:`

Comment: You could also iterate it the list like 
`for elem in permastorage:
     #Do stuffs with elem
     if storage[2] == elem.number`
Give it a try.

Comment: It did not work. It completely skipped the entire loop. The main problem it runs into when and if the loop starts (Such as when it is `len(permaStorage)+1` is that it the list index is out of range. The part where it checks if `storage[2] == permaStorage[i].number`

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate upto the last element of the list, not beyond.

Try -

`for i in range(0, len(permaStorage)):`

The list of numbers produced in `range()` is from the start, but not including the end, so `range(3) == [0, 1, 2]`.

So if your list `x` has length 10, `range(0, len(x))` will give you 0 through 9, which is the correct indices of the elements of your list.

Adding `1` to `len(x)` will produce the range `0 through 10`, and when you try to access `x[10]`, it will fail.